# Finding a basis for a given subspace of $\Bbb R^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Find a basis for the subspace $ W = \{(x, y, z, w) \in\Bbb R^4
: y − 2z + w = 0\}$. What is $\dim(W)$?

I don't seem to understand how to solve this problem. I just don't know where to start I am not given an A matrix to work with. possibly the b matrix is $[0, 1, -2,1]$ but is that enough to find the basis?

Comment: $[0, 1, -2,1]$ **is** your $A$ matrix; all you need to do is find a basis for its nullspace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, every vector in $W$ may be written as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\ y\\ z\\ 2z-y
\end{bmatrix}
=x
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\0\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix}
+
y
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 1\\ 0\\ -1
\end{bmatrix}
+
z
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\0\\1\\ 2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
One easily checks that the collection
$$
\mathcal B=
\left\{
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\0\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix}
,
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 1\\ 0\\ -1
\end{bmatrix}
,
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\0\\1\\ 2
\end{bmatrix}
\right\}
$$
is linearly independent. Hence $\mathcal B$ is a basis for $W$ which implies $\dim(W)=3$.

Comment: so the trick is to express the vector using the equation you are given, but what if you are given no equation. Assuming no equation given the basis would be the unit vectors in R^4?

Comment: Can you give me an example of a situation where you are not given an equation?

Comment: Find a basis for the subspace S
′ = {A ∈ M3,3 : A = −A^t} of 3 × 3 skew-symmetric matrices. What’s dim(S
′
)?

Comment: @user3424493 You have equations in that case too. If $A=\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c\\ d & e & f\\ h&i&j \end{bmatrix}$, then $A=-A^\top$ means $\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c\\ d & e & f\\ h&i&j \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} -a & -d & -h\\ -b & -e & -i\\ -c & -f & -j\end{bmatrix}$ so $A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & b & c\\ -b & 0 & f\\ -c & -f & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 4):

You could write every vector in the subspace as:
$$(x,y,z,w)=(x,2z-w,z,w)=x(1,0,0,0)+z(0,2,1,0)+w(0,-1,0,1)$$
Then being the vectors $(1,0,0,0),(0,2,1,0),(0,-1,0,1)$ independents the dimension of the subspace is 3 (because every vector is linear combination of that 3 vectors)